# CSS - Having a div fill the remaining vertical space

Tags: jquery, css

Please see a demonstration here: http://puu.sh/3YwRt.png

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elvista/7LBcr/2/

I am trying to make an outlook.com like chat in the sidebar.

I have managed to reverse engineer some of the codes from outlook.com and make a chat window similar to it. However I have a limitation that site does not have. I do not know the exact top value of the #chathistory because I might have one or more .widget with variable heights placed on top of the #chathistory.

Essentially, I have this code:

```
#chathistory {
    overflow-y: auto; 
    bottom: 60px;
    top: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

And I need it to function without the top:value.

Can it be done with CSS or do I need jQuery? If the latter can I have some guidance on how to since my jQuery skills are minimal at best please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[jsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/7LBcr/6/)

This solution requires jQuery but allows you to leave all other CSS unchanged and accounts for as many other `".widgets"` as you may have in the sidebar. ERRATA: You must remove the `top` styling for `#chathistory` in your CSS code, as seen in the fiddle.

```
var otherWidgets = $('#sidebar').find('.widget').not('#chatbar');
var maxBtm = 0;
$.each(otherWidgets, function (k, v) {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    var thisBtm = offset.top + $(this).height();
    if (thisBtm > maxBtm) {
        maxBtm = thisBtm;
        alert(maxBtm); // of course, remove this as you see fit
    }
});
$('#chatbar').css('top', maxBtm + 1);
$('#chathistory').css('top', maxBtm + 32); // aha - add this line, as well!!
```

[image: Here we go]

Comment: Hi! Thanks but it's not really working on the jsfiddle. The content seems to overlap and there is no scrollbars to show all the .msgs http://puu.sh/3YGrH.png

Comment: What browser are you using? Your fiddle results are very different than mine.

Comment: Interesting. I am using the latest Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Same here - Chrome 28 on Windows 7. Let me update the fiddle and re-link it

Answer (score 0):

I'll let you try to do this by yourself, since it is very "doable".

All the code you might need is :

```
$(element).css('top',X);
$(element).height(X); // Set height
$(element).height(); // Get height
```

Now, what you will basically do is get the overhall height of your sidebar, then substract the height of every widget to get the height for your #chathistory. You'll then modify "top" so that it equals the sum of every widget height above #chathistory.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you want:

http://jsfiddle.net/tprats108/7LBcr/3/

CSS:

```
#chatbar {
    height: 100%;  // This is pretty much the main difference (also removed top)
}

.first {
    height: 30px;
}
#sidebar, #chathistory, textarea {
    width:300px;
}
#sidebar {
    position:fixed;
    display:block;
    right:0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0
}
.widget {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 10px 0
}
#chathistory {
    overflow-y: auto;
    bottom: 60px;
    position: absolute;
}
textarea {
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
}
```

html: (i don't think i changed it aside from tidying it up)

```
<div id="sidebar">
    <div class="widget first">Variable content</div>
    <div class="widget" id="chatbar">
        <span class="username">John Doe</span>
        <div id="chathistory">
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Dolor Sit</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Amet Confus</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Dolor Sit</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Amet Confus</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Dolor Sit</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Amet Confus</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Dolor Sit</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Amet Confus</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Dolor Sit</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Amet Confus</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Lorem Ipsum</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Dolor Sit</div>
            <div class="msgs">This is a sample chat msg. Amet Confus</div>
        </div>
        <textarea rows="1" cols="30"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am afraid not. Two issues: The content's overlap and there is no scrollbars. http://puu.sh/3YFUM.png

Comment: Really? In the jsfiddle i don't think they overlap

Comment: oops i see it now, i'll check it out